# KMZ file in wrong coordinate system and won't transfer into correct one

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, utm, kmz

I'm using a pyroclastic flow simulation model (Titan2D Mass Flow Simulation GUI) that uses UTM WGS 1984 and from what I can tell, the coordinates that I'm inputting are all correct. When I view the output files within the program, they're completely correct (starting points, extents etc all use coordinates and all are correct) but when I put the downloaded KMZ files into Google Earth or any GIS program, they end up in UTM Zone 31N instead of in Tenerife, where I want them. They're at the correct latitude but are just in Algeria instead of in Tenerife!

I have access to QGIS, ArcMap and ArcGIS Pro and have been using ArcGIS Pro to try to 'Define Projection' and 'Project' and anything else I can think of (turned them into shapefiles and tried again to 'define projection' and 'project') but nothing seems to be working at all.

Is there any way to move them along the line of latitude from Algeria to Tenerife?
Does anyone have any suggestions as I need to move them over to Tenerife so I can create hazard maps for my dissertation?

Comment: Pretty much any time you're using Define Projection on a dataset with a previously defined projection, you're breaking that dataset. KML (and KMZ) is only possible in WGS84 degrees (GCS). If you want to reproject the data to UTM, you should first restore the original spatial references to all datasets, and if they don't align with project-on-the-fly then work that issue first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Titan2D, but Page 23 of the [User Guide](https://github.com/TITAN2D/titan2d/blob/master/doc/Titan2D_User_Guide.pdf) mentions a *Zone Override* setting when creating KML/KMZ files. The UTM Zone for Tenerife is 28N.

Comment: that's a really excellent point - I'm trying that now to see if it solves the problem, thank you!